# Forcing scientific ticks

Tags: plotting

I have looked into previous questions about forcing scientific notation frame ticks and even I do the same thing my plot still has the wrong ticks.

Instead of 1/1000 I want to have $10^{-3}$.

[image]

```
RegionPlot[{Subscript[C, WW] + Subscript[C, BB] < 0}, {Subscript[C, 
  WW], -1.1*10^(-3), 1.1*10^(-3)}, {Subscript[C, BB], -1.1*10^(-3), 
  1.1*10^(-3)}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.1* 10^(-3), 1.1*10^(-3)}, {-1.1*10^(-3), 
    1.1*10^(-3)}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{#, ScientificForm@#} & /@ 
    Range[-10^-3, 10^-3, 10^-3], {#, ScientificForm@#} & /@ 
    Range[-10^-3, 10^-3, 10^-3]}, ImageSize -> 450]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix this by writing you expression for the `FrameTicks` option is a much simpler way. To get the `ScientificForm` to format your limits correctly, you should note the use of 10.^-3 in place of 10^-3.

```
Plot[x, {x, -1.1*^-3, 1.1*^-3},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> ConstantArray[{#, ScientificForm @ #} & /@ 10.^-3 {-1, 0, 1}, 2], 
  ImageSize -> 450]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

The above plot doesn't print .001 as 1.*10^(-3) because, by default, numbers that can show all their significant digits when printed at normal output width are not printed in exponent form. However, we can suppress the default behavior. Like so:

```
tickF = 
  {#, 
   ScientificForm[#, 
     NumberFormat -> (Function[{m, b, e}, If [e == "", m, Row[{m, "×", 10^e}]]])]} &;

Plot[x, {x, -1.1*^-3, 1.1*^-3}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> ConstantArray[tickF /@ (10.^-3 {-1, 0, 1}), 2], 
  ImageSize -> 450]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

Need `.`s after each `10` to make `ScientificForm` working.

```
RegionPlot[{Subscript[C, WW] + Subscript[C, BB] < 0}, {Subscript[C, 
   WW], -1.1*10^(-3), 1.1*10^(-3)}, {Subscript[C, BB], -1.1*10^(-3), 
  1.1*10^(-3)},
 PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.1*10^(-3), 1.1*10^(-3)}, {-1.1*10^(-3), 
    1.1*10^(-3)}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{#, ScientificForm@#} & /@ 
    Range[-10.^-3, 10^-3, 10.^-3], {#, ScientificForm@#} & /@ 
    Range[-10.^-3, 10^-3, 10.^-3]},
 ImageSize -> 450]
```

> [image]

or

```
RegionPlot[{Subscript[C, WW] + Subscript[C, BB] < 0}, {Subscript[C, 
   WW], -1.1*10^(-3), 1.1*10^(-3)}, {Subscript[C, BB], -1.1*10^(-3), 
  1.1*10^(-3)},
 PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.1*10^(-3), 1.1*10^(-3)}, {-1.1*10^(-3), 
    1.1*10^(-3)}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{#, 
      If[# == 0, 0, 
         ScientificForm[#, 
          NumberFormat -> (Superscript[#2, #3] &)]] &@#} & /@ 
    Range[-10.^-3, 10^-3, 
     10.^-3], {#, 
      If[# == 0, 0, 
         ScientificForm[#, 
          NumberFormat -> (Superscript[#2, #3] &)]] &@#} & /@ 
    Range[-10.^-3, 10^-3, 10.^-3]},
 ImageSize -> 450]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

A post processing way would be more automatic.

Define below functions

```
ClearAll[changeTicks, changeTicksToScientificForm];

changeTicks[plot_, tickStringTransformFunc_, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{frameTicks, ticks},
   frameTicks = Quiet@AbsoluteOptions[plot, FrameTicks];
   ticks = Quiet@AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks];
   Show[plot
      /. (FrameTicks -> _) -> 
       Quiet@First[
         frameTicks /. 
          x_String :> If[x === "", "", tickStringTransformFunc@x]]
     /. (Ticks -> _) -> 
      Quiet@First[
        ticks /. 
         x_String :> If[x === "", "", tickStringTransformFunc@x]], 
    opts]
   ];

changeTicksToScientificForm[plot_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{},
  changeTicks[plot, ScientificForm@N@ToExpression@# &, opts]
  ]
```

Now

```
p = RegionPlot[{Subscript[C, WW] + Subscript[C, BB] < 0}, {Subscript[
     C, WW], -1.1*10^(-3), 
    1.1*10^(-3)}, {Subscript[C, BB], -1.1*10^(-3), 1.1*10^(-3)}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.1*10^(-3), 1.1*10^(-3)}, {-1.1*10^(-3), 
      1.1*10^(-3)}}, ImageSize -> 450];
changeTicksToScientificForm@p
```

gives

[image]

`changeTicksToScientificForm` suites for many other cases. Just apply it to the plots after they are generated. For examples

```
changeTicksToScientificForm@Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1000}]
```

gives

[image]

```
changeTicksToScientificForm@
 DensityPlot[x y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -100, 100}]
```

gives

[image]

```
changeTicksToScientificForm@Plot3D[x y^2 , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 100}]
```

gives

[image]

If you do not want to see small number becomes scientific notation, you can use for example `ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-3, 3}` option for `ScientificForm` in `changeTicksToScientificForm`, then you get

[image]